# Discrete vs continuous (dimension vs measure) for dates in tableau

Tags: graph, data-visualization, tableau-api, graph-visualization

I'm currently learning tableau and was creating a graph to map the unemployment with respect to each month. As the period of time was a measure, I dragged it in and it resulted in aggregation by month (of all years together) and a graph was displayed as such:

[image]

Now to plot it monthly for each subsequent year, I checked online and saw the conversion method where the same `MONTH(PERIOD)` was converted to a measure and it resulted in a plot like this:

[image]

Could someone please explain why does this work and how is a measure responsible for displaying data in such a way and not the month dimension. I cannot understand the plots when both the axes are measures.

Thank you

Comment: Think of a bank account.  Suppose you print your statement every week or day or month.  Even if you print your statement daily it doesn't mean that the moment you have not printed your statement, your account was empty. So if you plot your statement values in a chart that will be dimension plotting whereas if you plot amount balance in your account it will be a measure plotting.

Answer (score 1):

> ...saw the conversion method where the same MONTH(PERIOD) was converted to a measure.

It's not converted to a measure. `Period` is still a dimension, just a `Continuous` one. Measures and dimensions in Tableau can be either `Continuous` or `Discrete`. The ability to convert one to another depends on the data type of your field. For example, Dates can be converted between `Continuous` and `Discrete`, but Strings can't. The green colour isn't for measures - it's for the `Continuous` type of either measure or dimension.

Comment: I’d upvote 10 times if possible. gherka’s point is critical and so easily misunderstood. The choice of whether to treat a field as discrete or continuous only affects how values for that field are presented visually. The choice of whether to treat a field as a dimension or measure affects how the data values are grouped and aggregated, changing the level of detail of the visualization and the actual values available to plot, but does not dictate how those values are presented.